# What is the behavior of -f (force?) argument in npm cache clean?

Tags: node.js, caching, npm, command-line-interface, package

I've searched the web, but I couldn't get answer to my question. How is:

```
npm cache clean -f
```

Different from:

```
npm cache clean
```

I suspect `-f` is shorthand for `--force`, but even in official docs I wasn't able to find why one would use `-f`, what are upsides of it and what are downsides. I'm sure there's a warning when using `-f`, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at npm cache clean source code:

```
// npm cache clean [<path>]
function clean (args, cb) {
  assert(typeof cb === 'function', 'must include callback')

  if (!args) args = []

  var f = path.join(npm.cache, normalize(args))
  if (f === npm.cache) {
    fs.readdir(npm.cache, function (er, files) {
      if (er) return cb()
      asyncMap(
        files.filter(function (f) {
          return npm.config.get('force') || f !== '-'
        }).map(function (f) {
          return path.join(npm.cache, f)
        }),
        rm,
        cb
      )
    })
  } else {
    rm(f, cb)
  }
}
```

Link to the source code: https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/cache.js#L199

It looks like by default cache clean command browse through default npm cache directory and removes all files except file named `-`. This file is skipped by default, and is deleted only in force option.

The question is what is the use of dash as a filename? I have found the possible answer in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename). According to information provided in accepted answer, some programs use `-` file as standard stdout.

To sum up. Standard `npm cache clean` removes all cache files except `-` file which is used sometimes to store stdout content. However `npm cache clean -f` or `npm cache clean --force` removes all files.